# edge probability graph

Tags: graph-theory

I apologize if this is something very trivial, but I couldn't find an answer to it anywhere:

I have a directed graph with

`n = 280 nodes` and

`m = 64 edges`

Now, my question is: If I want to compare this graph to a G(n,p) random graph, how do I calculate `p`?

If `m = p*n(n-1)`, is it correct then to calculate `p` as

`p =  m/280(280-1)`

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I guess that would be $p = m / {n \choose 2} = 2m / n(n - 1)$, because ${n \choose 2}$ is the max number of edges.

Comment: It's a bit hard to do this comparison - It's going to be strange to compare a directed graph with an undirected graph.